# How to create static cells with dynamic cell heights with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7.3

I have looked at several tutorials that show how to set dynamic cell heights, but all of them only show it if you are using dynamic cells by setting the appropriate constraints and using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. However, I would like to do this for static cells.

I have a table view controller in my app that contains several cells that display a category with a disclosure indicator in which there is a title and then a description and the size of the description text varies. Thus, I would like the height of the cell to be dynamic per the size of the description text.

The reason why I am using static cells and not dynamic cells is because above the category cells I have a few cells with some designs that I could only get by using static cells and storyboarding.

I am using `iOS9`, `Xcode 7.3` and `Swift 2.2`

**UPDATE**

***Table View Controller Code***

```
import UIKit

class CategoriesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 2
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Per accepted answer below I added the two methods below to my table view controller and removed the 2 lines I had in viewDidLoad(). This did it for me! Keep in mind that I had to make sure all the labels in each cell used a top, bottom, leading and trailing constraint. Also, the number of lines for each label must be set to 0.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UILabel:**

Set `numberOfLines = 0` via programmatically or set lines to zero in attributes inspector of the `UILabel`.

[image]

**UITextView:**

Let's select your text view and uncheck the scrolling enabled like as below image.

[image]

Add the below code to your view controller:

**Swift 5:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

**Swift 2.2:**

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

Comment: I am not using a text view. I am using regular labels for my text.

Comment: However, adding the 2 methods did fix my issue. The cells are now being resized depending on the size of the label text. Thanks!

Comment: oh okay.Welcome friend :) Make compiler happy !

Comment: In storyboard when I check "automatic" for row height in a static table, storyboard wants to force the height to 44. If I don't make the height 44 everything is misplaced. It looks correct when the app is run, but it is very difficult to layout in interface builder when the height isn't 44. Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is set proper `AutoLayout` inside the `cell`, so the height increases based on the length of the description text.
 Then you need to set the following in your `viewDidLoad`

```
tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Please note: you need to set the `numberOfLines` of `UILabel` to 0

Answer (score 2):

@Forge, add please to your topic
Swift 4 variant:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Forge answer Swift 5 variant,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableView.automaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```