# Setting cell height for only one cell type and retaining dynamic heights for others

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView with dynamic heights for cells. However there is a particular cell type I want to assign a fixed height to. My code is as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 {
            guard let answerType = question.answerType else {
                return //What value here?
            }
            if answerType == .Text {
                return tableView.frame.height
            }
        }
    }
```

However I'm not sure what value to return in the guard statement. I don't want my other cells to be fixed height but instead remain dynamic. How can I go about doing this? Any pointers would be really appreciated! thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778849/how-to-create-static-cells-with-dynamic-cell-heights-with-swift/38780839#38780839

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` from the guard statement. It will return dynamic height for cell.